Issues with Serving Images Across Multiple Domains: Redirect Loop and Incorrect Referer Handling
I’m working on a project where I have two domains: imagedomain.com and i.imagedomain.com. The main domain (imagedomain.com) handles user interactions and access logic, while the subdomain (i.imagedomain.com) serves the actual image files. However, I’m running into issues with redirect loops and incorrect referer handling when trying to serve embedded images.
The Problem
Redirect Loops: Sometimes, when trying to access images, the browser gets stuck in a redirect loop.
Incorrect Referer Handling: Embedded images are occasionally treated as direct access, leading to unnecessary redirects.
The Setup Details
imagedomain.com handles the access logic and redirects.
i.imagedomain.com serves the actual image files, stored on an S3-compatible service (Wasabi).
What I've Tried
I ensured that the referer checks are in place to distinguish between legitimate embedded requests and direct access.
I confirmed that i.imagedomain.com is configured to serve images directly without any unnecessary redirects.
How can I correctly serve embedded images from i.imagedomain.com, similar to how Imgur does it, without triggering redirect loops or misidentifying them as direct access? What improvements can be made to the .htaccess and PHP script to ensure robust handling of these cases?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
The Setup
On imagedomain.com, I have the following .htaccess rule that redirects image requests to a PHP script:
RewriteEngine On
# Match image and video file requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|webm|bmp|tiff|svg)$ [NC]

# Avoid redirect loops by skipping requests already handled by image-proxy.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/image-proxy.php$ [NC]

# Redirect all other image requests to the proxy script
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|webm|bmp|tiff|svg)$ /image-proxy.php?image=$1 [QSA,L]

This is the PHP script (image-proxy.php) used to decide whether to serve the image directly or redirect:
<?php
// Get the image name from the URL
$imageName = basename($_GET['image']);

// Get the referer header
$referer = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

// Initialize the direct access flag
$isDirectAccess = false;

// Perform referer checks
if (empty($referer)) {
    // No referer typically means direct access (e.g., user entering the URL directly)
    $isDirectAccess = true;
} else {
    // Parse the referer domain
    $refererDomain = parse_url($referer, PHP_URL_HOST);

    if ($refererDomain !== false) {
        if (strpos($refererDomain, 'imagedomain.com') !== false) {
            // Legitimate request from within your domain (e.g., embedded images)
            $isDirectAccess = false;
        } else {
            // Referer from an external domain - likely direct access from elsewhere
            $isDirectAccess = true;
        }
    } else {
        // Could not parse the referer domain - treat cautiously as direct access
        $isDirectAccess = true;
    }
}

// Handle the request based on the checks
if ($isDirectAccess) {
    // Redirect to the image's page on your site
    header("Location: https://imagedomain.com/" . urlencode($imageName), true, 301);
    exit();
} else {
    // Serve the image directly from Wasabi (for embedded images and internal links)
    $wasabiUrl = "https://i.imagedomain.com.s3.wasabisys.com/" . $imageName;

    // Open the file on Wasabi to serve it
    $fileHandle = @fopen($wasabiUrl, 'rb');
    if ($fileHandle) {
        // Determine the MIME type by reading the file headers from Wasabi
        $fileHeaders = stream_get_meta_data($fileHandle);
        foreach ($fileHeaders['wrapper_data'] as $header) {
            if (stripos($header, 'Content-Type:') === 0) {
                header($header);
                break;
            }
        }

        // Serve the file content
        fpassthru($fileHandle);
        fclose($fileHandle);
    } else {
        // If the image is not found, return a 404 error
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        echo "Image not found.";
    }
    exit();
}


"// No referer typically means direct access" - it might as well mean that some firewall or browser extension filtered it out, for privacy reasons. Allowing access when the referrer is empty/not set, is the usual way to handle this.
